# Link MS SQL Server tables in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I wanted to know if it is possible to connect MS SQL Server tables in a 
MySQL server. Or if it can be done through Java DB. I mean, link tables of MySQL and MS SQL 
Server into JavaDB and then queries through JavaDB. If you know other good solutions, Okay 
anyway (excluding: (1) UnityJDBC because I already tried it and it isn't good for me; (2) 
'Linked Servers' of MS SQL Server because the company I work for is based on MySQL databases).

Answer (score 0):

There was some work a few years ago to create a FEDERATED_ODBC storage engine which would allow MySQL to access tables on another database instance through ODBC.

http://capttofu.livejournal.com/2456.html

I'm not sure how much bitrot it has developed.  If there is interest you may be able to get its creator to do some work on it.